# Barplot customization (add labels of two groups, minor gridlines)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have vector containing four numeric values, and with this values and code:

```
vector <- c(9, 10, 6, 5, 5)
graf <- barplot(vector, col="red", 
                names.arg=c("Leadership ","Management",
                            "Problem Solving ", "Decision Making",
                            "Social Skills"))

text(graf, 0.5, labels=vector)
```

I create this barplot

[image]

**MY DESIRED OUTPUT**:
 I would like to create (or customize ** x axe text position and group bars by PART1 and PART2 and alo add grindlines**) barplot like in picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the new line character \n in the names argument:

```
Names <- c("Leadership", "Management\n", "Problem Solving",
           "Decision Making\n", "Social Skills")
barplot(vector, col=2, names.arg = Names)
```

or use the `axis()` function:

```
b <- barplot(vector, col=2, names.arg = "")
axis(1, at= b, Names, line= 1, lty= 0)
```

Or creating a function, which set the line of the axis depending on odd or even number:

```
Names <- c("Leadership","Management",
           "Problem Solving", "Decision Making", "Social Skills")
b <- barplot(vector, col= 2, names.arg= "")
# function
foo <- function(x, y){
  if(x %% 2 == 0) LINE= y[1]
  if(x %% 2 != 0) LINE= y[2]
  axis(1, at=b[x, ], Names[x], line= LINE, lty= 0) }

sapply(1:length(vector), foo, c(0, 1))
```

And the final plot, using `rect`, `abline` and `text`. You have to set the positions by your own:

```
b <- barplot(vector, col= 2, names.arg= "")
abline(h= 0:10, lty= 2)
b <- barplot(vector, col= 2, names.arg= "", add= TRUE)

abline(v= 3.7, col= "blue")
rect(0, 10.5, 3.65, 11.5, col= "blue", xpd= TRUE) #xpd enables plotting outside the plot region
rect(3.76, 10.5, 6.25, 11.5, col= "blue", xpd= TRUE)
text(b[2,] ,11, "PART 1",col= "white", adj= 0.5, xpd= TRUE)
text(5, 11, "PART 2",col= "white", adj= 0.5, xpd= TRUE)

sapply(1:length(vector), foo, c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Or using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Set up a data.frame which works with ggpolt
Names <- c("Leadership", "Management",
           "Problem Solving", "Decision Making", "Social Skills")
# add \n
Names[seq(2, length(Names), 2)] <- paste0("\n" ,Names[seq(2, length(Names), 2)]) 
# data.frame, including a grouping vector
d <- data.frame(Names, vector, group= c(rep("Part1", 3), rep("Part2", 2))) 
# correct order
d$Names  <- factor(d$Names, levels= unique(d$Names))

# plot the bars
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x= Names, y= vector, group= group)) + geom_bar(stat= "identity") + theme_bw()
# use facet_grid for the groups
p + facet_grid(.~group, scales= "free_x", space= "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for detailed answer. That was much helpfull.